# How to use existing phpunit.xml in phing build.xml?

Tags: php, phpunit, phing

I have an existing **phpunit.xml** (configuration file for phpunit), which looks like this:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    strict="true" 
    verbose="true"
    colors="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Tests">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

As [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) says, I don't want to simply copy & paste content of **phpunit.xml** to my **build.xml** to run phpunit with the same configuration.

My target in **build.xml** for Phing looks like this:

```
<target name="unit-test">
    <phpunit printsummary="true" />
</target>
```

Even that phpunit should automatically find phpunit.xml (when I launch it manually as like entering "phpunit" to my terminal and push enter, it works) and use it, in case of phing, the output looks like this:

```
[phpunit] Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Incomplete: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.00122 s
```

So is there any way, how to reach described behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible [since](http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/751) phing 2.4.13 with the [configuration](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#PHPUnitTask) attribute:

```
<phpunit configuration="path/to/phpunit.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions would be

```
<exec command="phpunit" logoutput="/dev/stdout" />
```

But it's missing the whole sugar around connection phpunit & phing.

I am afraid there are no other elegant solutions as the TestRunner is completely different in [phing](https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/blob/master/classes/phing/tasks/ext/phpunit/PHPUnitTestRunner.php) & [phpunit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php).

Comment: I downvoted this, and can't undo. @Radek is actually right. https://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/1226 should make it possible.