# How to use phpunit in phing?

Tags: php, xml, configuration, phpunit, phing

According to
[How to use existing phpunit.xml in phing build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824932/how-to-use-existing-phpunit-xml-in-phing-build-xml)
It should be work to use phpunit.xml in phing like this

```
 <phpunit configuration="./phpunit.xml">
```

but it's mouse, don't know why?

xml like this

```
<target name="test" description="Run PHPUnit tests" depends="prepare">
            <phpunit printsummary="true" configuration="./phpunit.xml" pharlocation="${pharlocation.dir}" ><!--configuration="./phpunit.xml"-->
                <formatter type="xml" todir="${xmlreport.dir}" outfile="${reportxml.dir}"/>
            </phpunit>
            <phpunitreport infile="${xmlreport.dir}/${reportxml.dir}" format="noframes" todir="${htmlreport.dir}" styledir="${xsl.dir}" />
</target>
```

run result like this,the phpunit donot run.I confirm the phing has find the phpuntil.xml ,when I change the name to a wrong name,the phing will prompt file donot exist.

> autotest > prepare:
>
> autotest > test:
>
> [phpunit] Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Incomplete: 0,
>   Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.00033 s
>
> BUILD FINISHED
>
> Total time: 0.5406 seconds

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post links to code or images of code-- no one can copy your code to work with it if it is in an image file. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to learn more about formatting your questions. You can paste your code into your question, select it, and hit the "{}" button to indent a code block. While you are at it, you might peruse the topics discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: use `phing --verbose` to see what phpunit command is run

Answer (score 0):

Your Phing version is not compatible with newest PHPUnit namespaces, update  Phing to v3.

Source:

- [Phing and PHPUnit, just cant get even the most basic thing running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907053/phing-and-phpunit-just-cant-get-even-the-most-basic-thing-running)
- [Phing with PHPUnit 0 tests executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833168/phing-with-phpunit-0-tests-executed)