# Phing with PHPUnit 0 tests executed

Tags: php, xampp, phpunit, phing

I'm trying to execute `PHPUnit` with phing but i'm finding some errors.

I have my target:

```
  <target name="tests">
    <phpunit pharlocation="C:/xampp/php/phpunit.phar" printsummary="true" haltonfailure="true" haltonerror="true">
        <formatter type="xml" usefile="false"/>
        <batchtest>
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="tests/*Test*.php"/>
        </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </phpunit>
</target>
```

But when i execute i have:

```
     [phpunit] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     [phpunit] <testsuites>
     [phpunit]   <testsuite name="AllTests" tests="0" assertions="0" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.000000"/>
     [phpunit] </testsuites>
     [phpunit] Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Incomplete: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.00496 s
```

I don't know why 0 tests executed. If i remove the pharlocation i have error on testX,

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found.

So, when i don't put pharlocation it found tests, but if i put pharlocation it doesn't work.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Phing 2.* it's not compatible with new PHPUnit's namespaces.

- Old namespace: `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`
- New namespace: `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

Try using Phing 3: https://www.phing.info/get/phing-3.0.0-alpha1.phar

Source: https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/issues/659